# Sailsjs upload file nodejs v 18

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js

I have the following problem, I work with Sailjs but on this occasion they asked me for compatibility issues to use Nodejs v18 which there is no problem except now that I have to upload some files through skipper-gridfs but apparently it does not create the file for me but I don't see anything in fs.files. This is my code:

Then checking the endpoint apparently it works because it uploads information in fs.chunks but NOT in fs.files.

I tried changing the versions of Nodejs and they work in versions prior to Node 14, but not for Node version 18.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.